# Github pages no despliega correctamente la pagina

Tags: html

Estoy empezando con el tema de diseño web. Tengo una pequeña pagina web que estoy creando y deseo desplegar lo que tengo hasta el momento en Github Pages. El problema es que cuando lo despliego ocurren varios errores: no me carga algunas imágenes, tampoco me carga archivos de audio, no carga el bootstrap y tampoco carga los links que tengo hacia las otras paginas de "inicio de sesión", "contacto" y "registro". ¿Algún tip de como poder desplegar todo correctamente?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Son problemas con las rutas, un error común en novatos, revisa la consola  y ve si tienes errores 404, revisa con que enlace salen las rutas y arréglalas en caso de estar mal.

Comment: Muchas gracias! evidentemente era un tema de rutas. En algunos casos se puede dejar con solo / en otros, aun no entiendo por que, toca con ./ (en Github). En local me funciona perfectamente.